# Devices on my wifi cannot access Pi Samba share

Tags: networking, windows, samba, file-sharing

Both my Android phone and Windows PC cannot access my Samba share despite everything being on the local network. Windows can see `RASPBERRYPI` but when I try to double click it and view its contents it say the following.

```
Windows cannot access \\RASPBERRYPI
```

I have an external USB drive formatted with `ext4` and automounted with `/etc/fstab` using the command. The drive mounts fine and I can create files without `sudo`.

```
UUID=123a1aa12-d272-32fa-8rd0-7sb5aa0d7e15 /externalDrive auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

The mounted folder has these permissions.

```
drwxrwxrwx   4 pi   users  4096 Apr  3 19:46 externalDrive
```

The folder I've shared at `/externalDrive/localShare` has these permisssions.

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 pi   users  4096 Apr  3 19:45 localShareFolder
```

The settings in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` are the following. I cleared all comments and default shares, but even before that I was having the same problem.

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes

[localShare]
   Comment = PiLocalShare
   Path = /externalDrive/localShareFolder
   Browseable = yes
   Writeable = Yes
   only guest = no
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   Public = yes
   Guest ok = yes
```

Comment: 1) Have you read /var/log/samba/log.%m ? 2) Mountpoint should be `/mnt/externalDrive` and not `/externalDrive`. 3) Add to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` for `[localShare]` the respective `force user = nobody` and `force group = nogroup`.

Answer (score -1):

the problem can be:

The Sharing Proprierities in your RPi, you are visible but the contents are blocked;

IP Configuration, the both devices have to be connected by the same way, normally by LAN, because the WiFi's and LAN's IPs aren't the same;

**SOLUTION**

You can share your Raspberry Pi's files and folders across a network using a piece of software called Samba, a Linux implementation of the Server Message Block protocol. You'll need to install this software:

`sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin`

Samba contains the SMB protocol, support for the Windows naming service (WINS), and support for joining Windows workgroups. A workgroup is a group of computers on a local network that can access eachother's folders. Samba-common-bin contains a tool that you'll need to register users with Samba. Once these packages have finished installing, you need to edit the Samba configuration file:

`sudo leafpad /etc/samba/smb.conf &`

Find the entries for workgroup and wins support, and set them up as follows:

`workgroup = your_workgroup_name
wins support = yes`

The name of the workgroup can be anything you want, as long as it only contains alphabetical characters, and it matches the name of the workgroup that you want to join.

You also need to add the following section of code to `smb.conf`:

`[pihome]
   comment= Pi Home
   path=/home/pi
   browseable=Yes
   writeable=Yes
   only guest=no
   create mask=0777
   directory mask=0777
   public=no`

Scroll down `smb.conf` until you see a section called Share Definitions, and add this code there. The path should point to the drive or folder that you want to share. I've set `'only guest'` and `'public'` to `'no'` so that Samba prompts for a password when I visit the folder that I've shared. This means that when I'm using a Windows PC, I can login to the shared folders on my Pi, and I'll have the same read/write permissions that user pi has.

Now type this command in a terminal, and enter pi's password twice:

`smbpasswd -a pi`

If you have a PC or laptop connected to your workgroup, you should be able to see your Raspberry Pi in Windows Explorer under Network.

I Hope This Help ;)

IanPP

Comment: given the OP is already using samba how does this answer the quiestion?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Part of this is to confirm if it is well configured and he needs to add thet code to `samba.conf`